# How to force the type of a variable in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to write some function that converts a mongoose `User` model to a string with bullet points:

```
// Simplified version so you get the idea
interface IUser {
  name: string
}

function userDetails (user: IUser, keys: string[]): string {
  return keys.map((k: string): string => {
    return `- ${k} : ${user[k]}`
  })
  .join('\n')
}
```

But I'm having a strange compiler error, where `user[k]` is underlined:

> Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.

Is there a way to "force" typescript to admin that `user[k]` is a string ? 
I tried `user[k] as string` or `<string> user[k]` without success.

Also, if I remove the `${user[k]}` from the returned string, then the compiler stop complaining

Appart from the compiler error, everything works at runtime.

Thanks !

Comment: How about `<string>(<any>user)[k]`?

Comment: Which version of TypeScript? Your example [works in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IUser%20{%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A}%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20userDetails%20%28user%3A%20IUser%2C%20keys%3A%20string[]%29%3A%20string%20{%0D%0A%20%20return%20keys.map%28%28k%3A%20string%29%3A%20string%20%3D%3E%20{%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%60-%20%24{k}%20%3A%20%24{user[k]}%60%0D%0A%20%20}%29%0D%0A%20%20.join%28%27\n%27%29%0D%0A}).

Comment: @Ryan it works ! \o/ thanks a lot. You can write it as an answer if you want

Comment: @Paleo I'm using typescript 2, with the `noImplicitAny` flag. I suspect mongoose to have something to do with this. I've not been able to reproduce the bug using a simple script...

Comment: I never used `noImplicitAny`. Maybe it is a limitation. I'll add an answer, even I'm unsure, because comments are too limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function userDetails(user: IUser, keys: string[]): string {
    let dic: { [prop: string]: string } = <any>user
    return keys.map((k: string): string => {
        return `- ${k} : ${dic[k]}`
    })
    .join('\n')
}
```